# Disable drag/sorting for Entity Browser

Tags: 9

I'm using Entity Browser and the Inline Entity Form module with Drupal 9.

Right now when you view the form it shows you the currently existing values with options to edit and remove. The thing is that this view can be resorted by dragging... but I don't want this functionality. I feel like I've gone over the various configurable options in the GUI but can't find a way to turn this off. Am I missing something? Do I need to use a theme hook or something?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up using a function to strip the sortable class from the element, but I wish there was something more elegant.

Comment: You can answer your own question. Others can provide different or better answers.